# Index problem when dowloading data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the total return (last price - first price)/first price. I would like to do it directly dowloading the data from yahoo without dowlading previously the csv file and then uploading it into pyhton.

Any idea why the error and how to solve it?

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import yfinance as yf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import datetime as dt

start=dt.datetime(2019,5,1)

end=dt.datetime.now()

data= yf.download('TSLA',start,end)['Adj Close']

data = pd.DataFrame(data).dropna()

total_return = (data[-1] - data[0]) / data[0]


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       2894             try:
    -> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
       2896             except KeyError as err:
    
    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
    
    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
    
    KeyError: 0
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-45-bb800ce55aa9> in <module>
    ----> 1 total_return = (data[0]- data[0])/ data[0]


~\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you neglected to specify the DF column you want to use.
In that last line, replace each reference to `df` with `df["Adj Close"]`.

```
total_return = ( data["Adj Close"][-1] - data["Adj Close"][0] ) / data["Adj Close"][0]
```

For the code

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data).dropna()
print(data["Adj Close"][-1], data["Adj Close"][0])
total_return = ( data["Adj Close"][-1] - data["Adj Close"][0] ) /
                 data["Adj Close"][0]
print(total_return)
```

The output is

```
570.22998046875 46.801998138427734
11.1838810980284
```